# Is there 'imagecreatefromjpeg' function in python like in PHP ?

Tags: php, python, django

I'm trying to add a cover profile into my web application that could be repositionned ..
I found a useful tutorial in this [link](https://w3lessons.info/2014/08/31/facebook-style-cover-image-reposition-using-jquery-php/)

The problem is that the server side code is in `PHP` and I'm working with `PYTHON` and `Django` .

I can't find some functions used in `PHP` like  `imagecreatefromjpeg` , `imageSY` , `imagedestroy` ...etc..

Any help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`imagecreatefromjpeg` is part of the GD library, so if you want roughly the same interface than what you have in PHP your best bet is to find GD bindings for Python

Here is a link to one: https://github.com/Solomoriah/gdmodule

And its corresponding function from its doc:

```
image(image[,(w,h)] | file | file,type | (w,h))
  create GD image from 
    - file.(png|jpeg|gd|gd2|xbm|xpm),
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Lepidosteus for the precious direction..

I have googled around and I found this useful link  [Alternative for PHP GD library in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943457/alternative-for-php-gd-library-in-python) in `Stack Overflow` .